# Can I 'restart' ended mediaSource?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, media-source

I implemented a adaptive html5 player with media source extension, and get stuck on logic about playback goes to very end.

I find out that `mediaSource.endOfStream()` must be invoked before playback ends, in order to see `ended` event emitted by `<video>` element.

After endOfStream invoked, `mediaSource.readyState` will become `ended`, and sourceBuffers already attached to it is still there. (not being removed)

ended readyState description at mediaSource spec:

> The source is still attached to a media element, but endOfStream() has been called.

In other word, mediaSource marked as ended but still attached to video element.

The scenario is: **I would like to replay this playback.**

Is there any way to 'restart' this mediaSource?

b/c mediaSource still attached to video element, so `videoElement.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource)` doesn't work. And also only a `closed` mediaSource can be attached, so when invoking this, mediaSource is closed, and sourceBuffers are removed.

I don't see any other method related in spec, or maybe my attempt (restart mediaSource) is totally wrong?

Does anyone have any idea?
Any comment/advice would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is answered in https://web.dev/media-mse-basics/

> If `MediaSource.readyState` value is `ended`, calls like `appendBuffer()` and `remove()`, or setting `SourceBuffer.mode` or `SourceBuffer.timestampOffset` will cause this value to transition to `open`. This means you should be prepared to handle multiple `sourceopen` events.